# SSRS red squiggly line under visibility expression

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services

I have a report where I want to hide certain elements based on a conditional expression. However, I'm getting the red squiggly line under the field even though I think it exists.

[image]

In this case, I want to hide the element if the HasQuotasGlobal field does not contain a 1. This particular dataset always has exactly one row, so I'm using the aggregate First() function, which contains the reference to the dataset context.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my expression?

I can confirm that it is not working as expected. The report runs, however the expression always evaluates to false, meaning that the element is displayed even when it should not.

Comment: Which certain elements you want to hide ?? it is in matrix, table or a textbox ??

Comment: @Manoj The elements are in the body, not inside a matrix/tablix. Placing the elements inside a tablix is my backup solution if I cannot resolve the problem directly. There are two elements, a textbox and a subreport.

Answer (score 3):

Don't worry about the squiggly line. If there is a real Syntax Error the report will not be shown in preview, and you will get an error message instead. If you can see a preview, then the expression is valid.

To debug this problem, add a Textbox with the value you are testing in it

```
=First(Fields!HasQuotasGlobal.Value, "CountryData")
```

and another Textbox with the IIF too

```
=IIF(First(Fields!HasQuotasGlobal.Value, "CountryData") = 1, True, False)
```

Then you will know how the expression is being evaluated.

Remember that the visibility expression has TRUE = Hidden and FALSE = Visible.